# Datanucleus fetchgroup composite key

Tags: datanucleus, composite-key

I am trying to map a class with composite key in datanucleus. The primary key is composed of two foreign keys and I can't seem to be able to include these foreign classes in the fetchgroup:

Using annotations :

```
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = idElementOne, allowsNull = "false")
 private Long idElementOne;

 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = "idElementTwo", allowsNull = "false");
 private Long idElementTwo;
```

works

```
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = idElementOne, allowsNull = "false");
 private ElementOne elementOne;

 @Column(name = "idElementTwo", allowsNull = "false");
 private Long idElementTwo;
```

works

but

```
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = idElementOne, allowsNull = "false")
 private ElementOne elementOne;

 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = "idElementTwo", allowsNull = "false");
 private Long idElementTwo;
```

does not.

How am I meant to do ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned any fetch group metadata or use of the fetch group API. So no idea why you think something will be in a particular fetch group

Comment: @DataNucleus I don't want it in a particular fetch group but in the default one. My problem is that I can retrieve ElementOne class in my second example but in the third, when I annotate two primary keys, I get a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError` on elementOne.

Comment: Yes, but you don't provide your PK class, so no comment is possible

Comment: @DataNucleus Thanks for you time. I went through the PrimaryKey classes doc again and tried creating that PK class. The doc example uses primitive types. But I would need to have ElementOne & ElementTwo properties and I don't understand how I can respect the "Constructor accepting a String parameter" requisite.

Comment: look at "CompoundIdentity" relation doc (which is what you have there). That gives an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments from DataNucleus user and documentation from the official website here is what I was missing.

ElementOne needs a [PrimaryKey class](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/primary_key.html) so that we can [use a constructor accepting a string argument](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/compound_identity.html) in the main class' PrimaryKey.

ElementOne PrimaryKey class:

```
public static class PK implements Serializable
{
        public Long idElementOne;

        public PK()
        {
        }

        public PK(String s)
        {
            this.idElementOne = Long.valueOf(s);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "" + idElementOne;
        }

        //...
    }
```

Main class with its PrimaryKey class:

```
 @PersistenceCapable(objectIdClass=PK.class)
 public class MainClass{

 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = idElementOne, allowsNull = "false")
 private ElementOne elementOne;

 @PrimaryKey
 @Column(name = "idElementTwo", allowsNull = "false");
 private Long idElementTwo;

 //...

 public static class PK implements Serializable
 {
        public Long idElementTwo; // Same name as real field in the main class
        public ElementOne.PK elementOne; // Same name as the real field in the main class

        public PK()
        {
        }

        public PK(String s)
        {
            String[] constructorParam = s.split("::");
            this.idElementTwo= Long.parseLong(constructorParam[1]);
            this.personne = new Personne.PK(constructorParam[2]);

        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "" + idElementTwo+ "::" + this.personne.toString();
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

PS: Examples from DataNucleus website use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) which is [not implemented in GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=537), use String.split() instead. Moreover the java doc states that:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   split method of String or the
>   java.util.regex package instead.